# Rails tests failing, for a valid value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have following model `Product` and test for the same. When I try to run the test, I get failure for assertion on valid value,  `assert product.valid?`, on line number 22.
Could you please tell why ?

Code :

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
 test  "product must not accept with empty attributes" do
  product = Product.new 
  assert product.invalid?  
  assert product.errors[:title].any?  
  assert product.errors[:description].any?
  assert product.errors[:price].any?  
 end

 test "product must not acept invalid amount values" do
  product = Product.new(:title => "test title",
                        :description => "test description", 
                        :image_url =>  "image_url"
                       )
  product.price = -1
  assert product.invalid?
  product.price = 0
  assert product.invalid?
  product.price = 1
  # Line number 22 below
  assert product.valid?
 end
end
```

And

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :description, :image_url, :presence => true
  validates :price, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.01}
  validates :title, :uniqueness => true
  validates :image_url, :format => {
    :with => %r{\.(gif|png|jpg)$}i, 
    :message => 'must be a URL for image'
  } 
end
```

[image: This is the error]

Comment: Please post code not screenshots from your editor. That way people can cut and paste it more easily.

Comment: @Telemachus Sorry for that. But , how to enable line numbers while pasting code ?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way. You just stick a comment in line 22, saying '# Line 22 - should be valid' or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image_url is not valid according to the validations in your Model declaration.

Comment: Don't feel ashamed! I suggest composing a set of valid model attributes to reuse in your tests.

Comment: Sorry to ask one more question. How do people debug ruby code (I come from eclipse and java, where debugging is very easy) ?

Comment: nobody:  look into the pry gem.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails